# Call Python functions from JSON in a parser

Tags: python, json

Is possible to call Python functions from JSON?

Something like a JSON including 2 numbers, and a link to the function that does something with these 2 numbers.

I can parse the JSON file retrieving data from it, but I am not sure how do I call a function while parsing. In the parser I could hardcode the operation, adding something in the JSON that identify the operation (A for add, S for subtract and so on); so the parser know the operation reading the letter passed in a field.

Although Ideally I would like for the parser to just read the JSON file and retrieve the correct functions in another Python module, so I don't have to modify the parser every time that some new class is written, that does something different with these numbers.

Is this possible to be accomplished in Python?

Comment: Just think of JSON as a serialization format. Just deserialize (decode) and use the resulting Python structure however you want.

Comment: Thanks @Keith; I didn't consider the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

"Specializing JSON object decoding" from [the Python standard library documentation;](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) (read: the Python foundation wrote the following block of code)

```python
import json
def as_complex(dct):
    if '__complex__' in dct:
        return complex(dct['real'], dct['imag'])
    return dct

json.loads('{"__complex__": true, "real": 1, "imag": 2}',
           object_hook=as_complex)
```

```python
import decimal
json.loads('1.1', parse_float=decimal.Decimal)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply (hence my upvote), but it would be useful to actually have something more than copy and paste from the documentation.

Comment: I may have misread your question too, I now think making a new subclass of [JSONDecoder](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder) that does what you want would be a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ijson library to iterate through the JSON: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson/

The ijson documentation provides a couple examples of how to iterate through JSON and do processing based on what it finds.

If you paste an example of your JSON and what you want to achieve, we can give you more focused help.